# Video capture/Screenshot

Tags: c#, slimdx

I try to stream my desktop, the problem is I have 8/10 fps when I use GDI, and 1 fps when I use SlimDX.

GDI

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1680,1050);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0,0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(1680,1050));
```

SharpDX

```
PresentParameters present_params = new PresentParameters();
present_params.Windowed = true;
present_params.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
present_params.BackBufferCount = 1;
present_params.FullScreenRefreshRateInHertz = 0;
Device d = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, present_params);

Surface s = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(d, 1680, 1050, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);

d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);

bmp = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(s, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp));
```

And...I need to backup the surface in a Bitmap.
Thank in advance !

Comment: Not sure what your question is.

Comment: How to have better performance ?

Comment: What kind of testing have you done to determine the cause of the problem?  Have you tried re-sampling the bitmap down to lower bpp?  Have you tried clipping a smaller area of the screen to see if the performance improves?

Comment: Have you tried reusing the bitmap? Looks to me like you're allocating a new bitmap (at that resolution, roughly 7MB of memory for each bitmap) for every frame. That's going to be incredibly slow...no way around that.

Comment: Have you tried reusing the bitmap ? Yes it does not change. Have you tried re-sampling the bitmap down to lower bpp? Yes have 60 fps in 640*480 and I have 30 fps with a bitmap in 1680*1050 and a CopyFromScreen in 640*480. I forgot to say that I send udp data (so I serialize the bitmap).

Comment: Sorry for the double post but If I don't send the bitmap, in 1680*1050 I have 30 fps, whereas if I send the bitmap I have 18 fps.

Comment: No ideas ? When I put CopyFromScreen in a thread, I have 20 fps. But i think that SharpDX is faster than GDI, but how ?